# Stop a docker-compose service which is using environment variable from an other repertory on the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a compose file at `/opt/myapp/docker-compose.yml` (upon others at the same place).

I want to run `docker-compose stop` but from an other location on the host machine, let's say `/home/username/scripts/`. When I run:

```
docker-compose -f /opt/myapp/docker-compose.yml stop
```

it raises this error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '/opt/myapp/docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.myapp-db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.myapp-nginx.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

I suspect this is because I've set up these port values using environment variables which are defined in a `.env` file that stands nearby the `docker-compose.yml` file. E.g.:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  dbdata: {}

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 
      POSTGRES_USER:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:5432

  web:
    image: nginx
    environment:
      NGINX_HOST:
      NGINX_PORT:
    volumes:
      - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
    ports:
      - "${PORT2}:80"
```

#### Question

How could I properly stop (and after that I'll need to start it again from the same location) the services defined in that docker-compose file, taking into account the correct environment variables, but from an other location on the host machine?

Comment: Please help to share your `docker-compose.yml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**option 1:**

export value of `MY_APP_PORT` variable directly in shell:

```
export MY_APP_PORT='put_your_ip_here' && docker-compose -f /opt/myapp/docker-compose.yml stop
```

**option 2:**

use `--env-file` parameter

```
docker-compose --env-file /opt/myapp/.env -f /opt/myapp/docker-compose.yml stop
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

**option 3:**

define path to your `.env` file in `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  dbdata: {}

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 
      POSTGRES_USER:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - /opt/myapp/.env
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:5432

  web:
    image: nginx
    environment:
      NGINX_HOST:
      NGINX_PORT:
    volumes:
      - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
    env_file:
      - /opt/myapp/.env
    ports:
      - "${PORT2}:80"
```

https://medium.com/better-programming/using-variables-in-docker-compose-265a604c2006

**option 4 :**

send value of `MY_APP_PORT` variable via `-e` flag

```
docker-compose -f -e MY_APP_PORT='put_your_ip_here' /opt/myapp/docker-compose.yml stop
```

Comment: I was thinking that if the `.env` path is not manually set up in the compose file, it was  implied. But in the current situation, it doesn't seem to be the case actually. Option 2 was OK for my usage. But thanks for your expanded answer, it's really appreciated.